# How do I make a border size itself depending on what it is called on?

Tags: html, css

What can I do to make it so that a border is only as wide as the p element it is applied to in CSS?

I also want to make it so that it auto-changes the size of the border if I were to change the text?


This is what it looks like without any fixing:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwmlV.png)

This is what it looks like when I manually change the size and then change the text:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5gIf.png)


I just want it to change depending on the length of the text. Thanks!

Comment: display:inline-block to the element? (or display:table or float:left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display inline-block will do the trick.

```css
div p{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Home</p>
<div>
```